# STL vector memory leaking on insert from other vector and emplace_back

Tags: c++, vector, std

I'm writing my own engine right now and I just wrote rendering code.
The rendering is done by passing shared_ptr of DrawBatch to each object and this objects "draws" to it.

Basicly im copying floats from each vertex to drawbatch buffer, then I render it all at same time.

Problem is that I'm leaking memory when I do vector.emplace_back and vector.insert.
Both vectors are reserved and shouldn't be realocated, they are cleared on start of each frame.

**Index loading:**

```cpp
void Leiko::Render::Types::DrawBatch::addIndex(std::vector<uint32_t> & data)
{
    uint32_t low = 100000000;
    uint32_t high = 0;
    for(auto a : data) {
        this->m_pIndexData.emplace_back(a + m_pIndicesIndex); //Leaks
        if(a > high) {
            high = a;
        }
        if(a < low) {
            low = a;
        }
    }
    m_pIndicesIndex += high - low;
}
```

**Vertex data copying:**

```cpp
void Leiko::Render::Types::DrawBatch::addVertexData(Leiko::Render::Types::Vertex & vertex)
{
    this->m_pData.insert(this->m_pData.end(),vertex.data().begin(),vertex.data().end()); // Leaks
}
```

Comment: A [mcve] would help.

Comment: How do you know that memory is leaking?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You can see it in Taskmgr, Its increasing fast in memory usage, then program freezes because of GC, memory usage drops back to low and increases again.

Comment: There is no "garbage collection" going on.  C++ is not Java or C#.  More likely, it is your code that is buggy, not vector.  Having said that, if you used `vector::clear`, then vector usually does *not* deallocate memory if the type being stored is trivially destructible, such as `uint32_t`.  Instead, `std::vector` simply sets the `size()` attribute to 0.

Comment: @MatějVrba C++ does not have garbage collection. And if memory usage drops back again, how is that a leak?

Comment: Something you're not happy about is going on in your program memory usage, but there's nothing here to justify your assertion that vector is leaking memory.